# Array of objects having duplicate attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of object how can I get those objects having duplicate attribute value.

```
var array = [{"id":1,"attr":5},{"id":2,"attr":3},{"id":3,"attr":5}];
```

Here it should return `array[0]` and `array[2]` because these elements having duplicate attribute value (attr=5).
and also return unique array.
array = [{"id":2,"attr":3}];

Comment: @Cerbrus, no, op wants the ones which are more than on time in the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz: The process of finding the duplicates doesn't change. Also: No attempt, this is just a requirement, expecting working code in return.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single loop approach for unsorted data by using a hash table for temporary collecting the first object of a group or just to indicate duplicates of the group.

```js
var array = [{ "id": 1, "attr": 5 }, { "id": 2, "attr": 3 }, { "id": 3, "attr": 5 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (o.attr in hash) {
            if (hash[o.attr]) {
                r.push(hash[o.attr]);
                hash[o.attr] = false;
            }
            r.push(o);
        } else {
             hash[o.attr] = o;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why `Object.create(null)` instead of just `{}`?

Comment: it creates an empty object without prototypes.

Comment: Why are you using a nested function like that to initialize the `hash`? That's not exactly beneficial for the code's readability / maintainability.

Comment: thats amazing @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator function and a nested loop to check for duplicates:

```
 function* dupes(arr, key) {
    for(const [index, el] of arr.entries()) 
      for(const  el2 of arr.slice(index + 1)) 
        if(index !== index2 && el[key] === el2[key])
           yield [el, el2];
 }
```

So you can use it as:

```
 for(const [dupe1, dupe2] of dupes(yourArray, "attr"))
    console.log(`${dupe1} collides with ${dupe2}`);
```